Remove disk from raid configuration
When running lsblk I get:
root@Ubuntu-2004-focal-amd64-base /dev # lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda           8:0    0  1.8T  0 disk  
├─sda1        8:1    0   32G  0 part  
│ └─md0       9:0    0   32G  0 raid1 [SWAP]
├─sda2        8:2    0    1G  0 part  
│ └─md1       9:1    0 1022M  0 raid1 /boot
└─sda3        8:3    0  1.8T  0 part  
  └─md2       9:2    0  3.6T  0 raid5 /
sdb           8:16   0  1.8T  0 disk  
├─sdb1        8:17   0   32G  0 part  
│ └─md0       9:0    0   32G  0 raid1 [SWAP]
├─sdb2        8:18   0    1G  0 part  
│ └─md1       9:1    0 1022M  0 raid1 /boot
└─sdb3        8:19   0  1.8T  0 part  
  └─md2       9:2    0  3.6T  0 raid5 /
nvme0n1     259:0    0  1.9T  0 disk  
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   32G  0 part  
│ └─md0       9:0    0   32G  0 raid1 [SWAP]
├─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0    1G  0 part  
│ └─md1       9:1    0 1022M  0 raid1 /boot
└─nvme0n1p3 259:3    0  1.8T  0 part

I would like to remove the nvme0n1 disk from the RAID configuration: so that it becomes an independent disk. How would i do it?
